# Entity Framework Returning Double Expected Results

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, duplicates

So this is an intermittent issues but highly frustrating

so for example I have a table with say 3 rows

```
id (pk),   value 1,    value2
1          a           b
2          a           c
3          a           d
```

in my dal

```
    private DB db = new DB();

    public List<entity> GetValues(string filter)
    {
        try
        {
            return db.entity.Where(x => x.value1 == "a").OrderBy(x => x.id.ToList();
        *Also Tried adding .Distinct*
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           *removed for brevity
        }
    }
```

now when I run this through without debug I get.

```
1,a,b
1,a,b
2,a,c
2,a,c
3,a,d
3,a,d
```

so returning the expected values twice.

however when I step through the code it will sometimes duplicate and sometimes return correct values.

what could be causing this duplication, or if unknown a way to manage it without performance drop (the real table is actually quite large)

Comment: Try to create `db` each time via `using(var db = new DB()){ //your code }`, instead of using property's value. Maybe other methods conflict with this one.

Comment: Are you using a view? if so this might help : http://jepsonsblog.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/enitity-framework-duplicate-rows-in.html?showComment=1348809764880#c1389404724781617559

Comment: @Richard, no joy with the .AsNoTracking() the issue remains,

Comment: @Slava I recreated the context before executing the query again no joy the issue remains.

Comment: What does your database return if you execute `SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE value1 = 'a' `?

Comment: Also check generated SQL: `var query = db.entity.Where(x => x.value1 == "a").OrderBy(x => x.id).ToString()`

Comment: If I use the generated SQL on SSMS it returns the one set of correct results. Just to Add when I step through the code it works as expected, its only when it runs itself that it duplicates.

Comment: At this case, may be the issue not with presented code, but with presentation logic?